# Int to char conversion, wrong number

Tags: java, unicode, casting

I have the following code:

```
int a=-12;
char b=(char) a;
System.out.println(b);
System.out.println(b+0);
```

It first prints out some empty character and then a number 65524. If I change `a` to, say, `16` the displayed number becomes 65520. If `a` is `-2`, the number is 65534.

If the number is positive and small enough it prints out characters out of Unicode table and returns the character's number (which is the same as a) if everything is OK and that previous strange number from above if it's not allright (if `a` is too big).

For instance, for `a = 8451` it returns ℃ (Degree Celsius) character and `a` itself (8451), but if `a=84510` it returns some strange Chinese symbol and a different from `a` number (18974). If `a` is even bigger `a=845100` it returns empty sumbol and 58668.

The question is, where do those numbers come from?

I've tried to find the answer, but wasn't lucky so far.

EDIT Since int to char is a narrowing conversion, please consider the same question with `byte` a. Too large numbers are obviously impossible now, but I wonder what happens with negatives - converting `byte a = -x` to char gives the same weird numbers as with `int a`.

Comment: The **char** data type is a single 16-bit Unicode character. It has a minimum value of '\u0000' (or **0**) and a maximum value of '\uffff' (or **65,535** inclusive).

Comment: @DevilsHnd, Thanks, I missed it out. Edited the post.

Comment: this might be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15176079/negative-char-value-java useful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`int` is a signed number which has **4 bytes** and **32 bits**. The **Two's complement** representation of -12 is

> 11111111 11111111 11111111 11110011 .

`char` is a unsigned which has **2 bytes** and **16 bits**.

```
int a=-12;
char b=(char)a;
```

**Two's complement** representation of b is

> 11111111 11110011

which is equivalent to **65524**

Comment: The first binary number is not the "Two's complement of **-12**", it is the two;s complement of (+)12, same for  the second binary number, it is not the :"Two's complement of b", it is just b (reduced to 2 bytes) - it is the two's complement of (+)12

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger the Two's complement of positive number starts with 0 and negative number starts with 1.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please tell, what happens if this `char` number gets after that converted into int? It looks like a widening conversion as well, so the leftmost bits should be filled with number's leftmost bit (1) and therefore in int we get `-12`, but it doesn't happen, it fills with zeroes.

Comment: @fengsmith you are confounding representation and operation: The two's complement **representation** of, e.g., -12 is the two's complement of 12. Definition: Two's complement of a number is equivalent to taken the ones' complement of that number and adding one; ones' complement of a number is obtained by inverting all its bits. So the two's complement of let's say 0011 (+3, assuming only 4 bits) would be 1100 + 1 = 1101

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger This is wiki:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement ,about the definition of Two's complement.

Comment: @parsecer yes, it fills with zeros including the leftmost bit.

Comment: @fengsmith exactly what I wrote - see second paragraph of that wiki article: "**The two's complement** of an N-bit number is defined as the complement with respect to 2N; **This is also equivalent to taking the ones' complement and then adding one**" and for ones' complement: "The ones' complement of a binary number is defined as the value obtained by inverting all the bits"

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger My English is poor.You can see :https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement right side:Some special numbers to note:−1 1111 1111,−64 1100 0000,127 0111 1111.You can see,the Two's_complement of positive number is starts with 0,the negative number is starts with 1.

Comment: @fengsmith - In that table Wikipedia is showing the "Two's complement **representaion**" of a number, not the "Two's complement of" that number. If you say/write "Two's complement of x" that usually means: apply the Two's Complement operation to the number x. Like "square of x" means to apply the square function to x. Or, maybe easier: "The two's complement representation of -12 is the two's complement of 12"

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Thank you.I understand, complement representaion and complement are two different concepts.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because `char` in **Java** is an unsigned "*Double Byte*" integer. When *Byte* is 8-bits, double-byte is 16-bits = 2 power by 16 = 65536 And you get ***Two's complement*** (*Binary* subtraction operation).

Because the number is unsigned all 16 bits are used to represent the integer, so when you give a negative number it creates an *overflow* you get the number which is (65536 + a), for example:

When `int a = -16;` you get `65536 - 16 = 65520`(in binary: 1111 1111 1111 0000)

When `int a = -2;` you get `65536 - 2 = 65534` (in binary: 1111 1111 1111 1110)

When `int a = 84510;` you exceed the limit of 65536 for `char`, so you are left with 18974 (84510 - 65536 = 18974).

You get a character from the *Unicode* table, I guess because it's the *character set* or *code page* you defined.

When you `cast` you should pay attention to the range of values of the data types you cast, in this case, the difference between `int` and `char`.

Comment: The 'machine' is Java. Your third paragraph contradicts the subsequent calculations.