# Does String's charAt() method ever return a negative integer value in Java?

Tags: java, string, charat

```
String data = //some String;
int val = data.charAt(2);
```

Can val ever have a negative value in any scenario?

Comment: This is just a restatement of "can a `char` have a negative value".  Read the language reference on the `char` datatype.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] and read [ask] before posting, to learn how to use this site.  Questions that show no research effort and can be easily answered by reading the relevant documentation are considered off-topic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [negative char Value JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15176079/negative-char-value-java)

Answer (score 4):

No.

> **char**: The char data type is a single 16-bit Unicode character. It has a minimum value of '\u0000' (or 0) and a maximum value of '\uffff' (or 65,535 inclusive).

[Source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

According to [the documentation on conversions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html), the conversion from `char` to `int` is a widening conversion. That page explicitly states (right above Example 5.1.2-1):

> A widening conversion of a `char` to an integral type `T` zero-extends the representation of the char value to fill the wider format.

which basically means that `ffff` will be padded on the left with zeroes to the integer `0000ffff`