# Assign negative value to char in Java

Tags: java, character

I want to assign a negative value to char in Java.
`Example: char a='-1'`
I tried the below example but an error occurs.

```
 char[] temp=new char[10];
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        if(condition met)
        temp[i]='-1';
    }
```

Comment: char a=(char)-1;

Comment: `-` and `1` are two separate `char`s. I recommend you use a `String` instead.

Comment: @JacobG. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'-'` and `'1'` are two separate `char`s, and they cannot be stored in a single `char` variable. Use a `String` instead. If you are using `-1` as some sort of an exit case, use some alphabetical character instead like `x`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, but char is 16-bit unsigned int so it will result in the char actually being 65535. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15176079/negative-char-value-java) for more info.

```
char a = (char)-1;
char b = (char)0;
System.out.println((int)a);
System.out.println((int)b);
```

Will result in output of:

```
65535                                                                                                                                                                                        
0
```